# Copiar datos a una tabla desde una subconsulta (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, update

Tengo un ejercicio propuesto en clase al que no consigo hacer funcionar correctamente. Le he dado mas vueltas, pero no consigo que actualice bien los datos. Os explico

Tengo que actualizar (UPDATE) los datos de una columna de una tabla(que actualmente están a NULL). Esos datos los obtengo a través de un SELECT y un INNER JOIN de 2 tablas. 
Este SELECT me da una columna con los datos que tengo que pasar y todo va ok, pero lo que no consigo es que se "copien" en la tabla "original".

Digamos que la "sentencia básica" es:

```
select SUM(total_linea)
from detalle_pedido
group by num_pedido;
```

Con esto obtengo una tabla, que ahora tengo que copiar en una columna de otra tabla. 
He estado leyendo y veo que hay que crear una "tabla intermedia" para poder hacer la "copia" ya que no permite al tener la tabla en uso y se haría usando un alias sobre el select de la query que vamos a envolver. Tras muchas vueltas solo llego a esto, que no funciona (salta error).
Empecé con esta sentencia:

```
    UPDATE pedido PE, detalle_pedido Dped SET total_pedido = (select SUM(total_linea)
from detalle_pedido
group by num_pedido)
WHERE Dped.num_pedido=PE.num_ped ;
```

y leyendo he sacado esta:

```
    update pedido SET total_pedido = (
        SELECT * FROM (select SUM(detalle_pedido.total_linea) as tabla1
                       from pedido inner JOIN Detalle_pedido ON detalle_pedido.num_pedido=pedido.num_ped
                       group by num_pedido) 
        AS tabla2);
```

pero ninguna funciona.

Alguna ayuda por favor?.

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido Eduardo, deberías mostrarnos el error que te sale en ambos casos. Pasarte por el [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer como funciona SO. Revisa en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) los apartados [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces la primer consulta, es probable que esta te retorne un conjunto de resultados (Una tabla con muchas tuplas, mejor dicho)
Pero no puedes hacer un UPDATE con muchas tuplas a la vez, sino con un único valor

Para que puedas hacer un UPDATE, necesitarías hacer uso de bloques de control en MySQL
Y con un puntero y un LOOP puedes ir actualizando uno a uno los valores